# Retrieve unknow key names and values from a JSON array list

Tags: arrays, json, go

```
[
        {"id_A": 1, "name_A": "Value_A"},
        {"id_B": 2, "name_B": "Value_B"}
]
```

"id_*" and "name_*" can change and I need to recover both the keys names to create a struct.

how can i do ?

https://play.golang.org/p/OXqpudiWWcH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have the key which is not fix, the only way you can use is interface{}
you need to unmarshal json to `[]interface{}` and using type assertion to `map[string]interface{}`

```
var body []interface{}

    _ = json.Unmarshal([]byte(json2), &body)
    fmt.Printf("Unmarshaled: %v\n", body)
    
    // range through array interface[]
    for _, opt := range body { 
    
        // assert interface{} to map[string]interface{} 
        if item, ok := opt.(map[string]interface{}); ok { 
            for v, opt := range item { 
                fmt.Printf("[%s] key -> %s  value -> %s\n", v, opt, "fake")
            }
        }
    }
```

the complete code based on your example
https://play.golang.org/p/PepxOVlB7u4